# How to zoom when scroll UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I add few labels in UIScrollView and I want when I scroll, the the middle label font size can become bigger. And the previous middle label font size shrinks to smaller. And the change happens gradually. Like below. Label 1 move to left shrink smaller and label 2 move to middle becomes bigger. All labels in a UIScroll view.

[image]

I tried some, like when scroll I tried zoom scroll page, seems complex than I thought...

Anyone has good idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple really. Just stick a `UIScrollViewDelegate` to the scrollview and do something like this..

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
        UIView *v = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        float position = v.center.x - scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        float offset = 2.0 - (abs(scrollView.center.x - position) * 1.0) / scrollView.center.x;
        v.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        v.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(v.transform, offset, offset);
    }
}
```

But, if you aren't impressed by the affine transform, you could still scale the rect using the `offset` factor and set the UILabel to `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`... and you are done!

Just make sure there is enough space! Else it could get out of hand very easily.

Assumptions :

1. There are no other views in the scrollview apart from these labels.
2. Its required to work just horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with CoreAnimation. You have to keep the index of the main label (that one in the center), and after scrolling is done or when scrolling starts (use some proper for you method in UIScrollViewDelegate) and simply shrink side labels by animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the size of the font bigger (with an animation block) when it is the middle one, and smaller when it is not.

You can add a category to UILabel with `-(BOOL)isMiddle` and set it to true/false.